# unlink function not working

Tags: php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['editpic'])) {
    $Id         = $_GET['editpic'];
    //Get Form Data from Data base against the Id
    $Edit_Query = "SELECT product_picture FROM products WHERE id='$Id'";
    $Result     = mysql_query($Edit_Query);
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
        $Old_File_Name = $Row['product_picture'];
    }
}

//To Update Record
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $Id                 = $_POST['id'];
    //To get file
    $Allowed_Extensions = array(
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'bmp',
        'gif'
    );
    $Allowed_Size       = 2097152;
    $File_Name          = $_FILES['newfile']['name'];
    $File_Size          = $_FILES['newfile']['size'];
    $File_Tmp           = $_FILES['newfile']['tmp_name'];
    $File_Explode       = (explode('.', $File_Name));
    $File_Extension     = strtolower(end($File_Explode));
    //Form Validation
    $Errormessage       = array();
    if (empty($File_Name)) {
        $Errormessage[] = "Please choose an image for your product";
    }
    if (!in_array($File_Extension, $Allowed_Extensions)) {
        $Errormessage[] = "Please choose only image file";
    }
    if ($File_Size > $Allowed_Size) {
        $Errormessage[] = "Maximum file limit is 2Mb";
    }
    if (empty($Errormessage)) {
        unlink("product_images/" . $Old_File_Name);
        if (move_uploaded_file($File_Tmp, "product_images/" . $File_Name)) {
            //To Rename the uploaded file
            $Random        = rand() * 1200;
            $File_New_Name = $Random . "." . $File_Extension;
            rename("product_images/" . $File_Name, "product_images/" . $File_New_Name);
            $Query  = "UPDATE products SET product_picture='$File_New_Name'    WHERE id='$Id'";
            $Result = mysql_query($Query);
            if ($Result) {
                header("location: manage_inventory.php");
            }

        }


    }

} //End isset update

?>
```

Everything is working except the unlink function I can't figure it out what is wrong with my old file variable, it's not deleting the existing file from folder.

Also I need to know why it looses the `?edit=$id` from url if any validation error occurred in my update.

Comment: I'm assuming that the user running apache (usually `www-data`) has correct file permissions on these images?

Comment: i m running it on my local host xamp yeah its apache

Comment: and it ws wrking fine before i made some changes in my code... its sure'ly a coding fault

Comment: Try to put this line at the top of your file and check for errors, if any:  
**error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);**

Comment: what does var_dump($Old_File_Name) produce?

Comment: Check if the file exists before deleting it, and check if you have write to delete

Answer (score 0):

First check to make sure the file exists, then test for the results of the unlink call.

Essentially:

```
$fileToDelete = "product_images/".$Old_File_Name;
if(!file_exists($fileToDelete)) {
   die("Eh? I can't delete something that doesn't exist!");
}

if(!unlink($fileToDelete)) {
   die("I can't delete that file, check my permissions");
}
```

(But with better error handling)